Mapstruct ignore nulls and collections
I'm facing an issue (?) with mapstruct regarding how it handle collections during the mapping phase in the generated code.
Already did some explanation on an issue on their github but I think here is a better place to understand if it is a misconfiguration or a real bug. The thread for the ones interested.
The problem
The mapper I'm using (full class here)
@Mapping(target = "financialPeriod", source = "financialPeriod", qualifiedByName = ["mapFinancialPeriod"])
abstract fun mapToDomain(form: PeriodMovementUpdateForm, @MappingTarget periodMovement: PeriodMovement)

Using the flag nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE I got the following generated java code:
@Override
public void mapToDomain(PeriodMovementUpdateForm form, PeriodMovement periodMovement) {
    if ( form == null ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( form.getFinancialPeriod() != null ) {
        periodMovement.setFinancialPeriod( mapFinancialPeriod( form.getFinancialPeriod() ) );
    }
    if ( form.getName() != null ) {
        periodMovement.setName( form.getName() );
    }
    if ( form.getDueDate() != null ) {
        periodMovement.setDueDate( form.getDueDate() );
    }
    if ( form.getValue() != null ) {
        periodMovement.setValue( form.getValue() );
    }
    if ( form.getDescription() != null ) {
        periodMovement.setDescription( form.getDescription() );
    }
    if ( periodMovement.getApportionments() != null ) {
        periodMovement.getApportionments().clear();
        List<Apportionment> list = apportionmentFormListToApportionmentList( form.getApportionments() );
        if ( list != null ) {
            periodMovement.getApportionments().addAll( list );
        }
    }
}

The weird stuff is when the code does periodMovement.getApportionments().clear();, since it is doing a clear before checking if the form.getApportionments() is null (like the other if's before the clear) it cause that if the form is null for this property, it clears the value in the target mapping instance resulting in a incorrect map since the value shouldn't be touched because of the flag to ignore null values.
The question is: why it clear the target list if the source is null and there is nothing to map?
